# Using "throw" script to stop Safari loading a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have the need to stop safari desktop from loading a script.

`"Throw"` may be an option but not sure how to target a specific browser.
would this target the browser correctly?

```
if ( /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { 
 ???? throw script "<script type="text/javascript">var cbuser = {name: '', email: '', message: ''}, access_token = 'Z2SxfM5dRhhjzKsm3Auhbi4', cburl = '//www.domain.com/';document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + cburl + 'assets/cmodule-chat/js/chatbull-init.js"></' + 'script>');</script>
" ????}
```

and how do i load throw and the script i dont want safari to use

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [head.js](http://headjs.com/) for browser detection and resource loading. Here's what it could look like in your case:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/1.0.3/head.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(head.browser.name != "safari") {
        head.load("path/to/conditional/file.js", function() {
            // File is loaded. Do something with it here
        });
    }
</script>
```

You could certainly wrap it in a doc.ready function too if you needed.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with this plugin?